# Can you identify this modified 1x1 plate?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Please can you identify this LEGO piece. I need to know what the name is from this piece.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  This would not be under tiles on bricklink because of the stud on top.  As you can see in the links in the answer these are under the "Plate, Modified" category.

Comment: What instructions are you trying to build?

Answer (score 5):

It's appears to be either [Part 4081a](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081a#T=C) or [Part 4081b](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081b#T=C).

I'm not sure if it is exactly the same, but this works as a starting point, I believe. The two linked pieces seem to differ only in the thickness of the ring of the added "limb".

I was unable to find a part like those that has a "hole" in the main stud.

Comment: While difference seem to be minor, both versions have significantly different options - tiles attached to thin ring sit flush with plate, size wise.

Comment: That is definitely the ‘b’-version. I have both a thick ring and a thin ring version of 4081 and ‘thin’ is really thin, not as thick as pictured. Also, that part list is not from an official LEGO set, so don’t pay attention to the open stud pictured, it might just be a quirk of the tool used by the designer of these instructions. (I know they are not official because LEGO does not put sizing info next to tiles).

Comment: Concur with @PhilB., that is definitely 4081b.

Comment: @PhilB. That's more like a clone piece of "b" version. Never seen such one produced by LEGO with hollow stud.

Comment: @PhilB "I know they are not official because LEGO does not put sizing info next to tiles" - this comment made lots of sense with the original, uncropped image, but might seem less relevant now that those tiles have been removed.

Comment: And the more I think about it, and about how the instructions were clearly NOT made by TLG, the more I realize the distinction between a and b might well be irrelevant - the software would just have used whatever image was available, regardless of what variant was actually in the model.

Comment: @RSchulz Clone brands probably don't even know "a" version ever existed as 34 years passed since its last production year.